# Spring cloud stream kafka- manual polling

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, error-handling

Need to trigger a consumption of particular topic on condition basis. How to do that in cloud stream Kafka?

Detailed Scenario:
We are processing messages from Kafka and updating in database. if DB is down/has any issues we are redirecting messages to a different topic.
Later when the DB is up again, we need to pause the actual consumption and poll the topic of failed messages and once those data are updated to DB then we need to resume the actual consumption.

We need to consider the order of messages here. Hence we took this approach.

Am currently trying with ConsumeFactory, but it's returning an empty collection.

```
Consumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer("0", "consumer- 
     1");
  consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("some-topic"));
  ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> poll = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10000));
  poll.forEach(record -> {
    log.info("record {}", record);
  });
```

Could someone help here or please suggest if we have any other option to handle this?

Comment: Are those "fail" messages the same you've polled from the original event or do they represent something that should be written to the DB first?

Comment: those messages need to be updated in DB first.

Comment: So just to be clear: you're polling messages from topic A, process them and write them to DB, but when the DB is not available you write the processing results to topic B. Then when the DB is up again topic B needs to be "drained" first before anything is writen to the DB? Would it be an option to always write to topic B and have a connector do the writing? That way you don't have to coordinate polling from A and draining B which would make your architecture more robust and easier to reason about.